# Is there a way to sync 2 databases in android?

Tags: android, database, synchronization, provider

I saw a lot of tutorials on syncing an android database on a cloud server but this is not what I need.
I have to sync my own application provider with an android native provider(e.g MediaStore). I am still looking into **AbstractSyncAdapter** API, though, most of the tutorials, again, uses this to sync in a server instead of another local provider. Also, it needs an Account which I think is unnecessary for my application.

I have already considered other options like using **ContentObserver** and catching the **ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED** intent but it would mean I have to check all changes made in the whole database since there is no way for me to know what exact row or column has changed. I am, by the way, developing in Android 2.2(Froyo/API level 8).

Comment: FYI: Android 2.2/API Level 8 is not Gingerbread, it is called Froyo.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm also working on Gingerbread. Thanks!